# How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

Tags: java, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit, expandable

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

How to print this Json response from api Call using Retrofit (parent-child) hirarchy or tree? in exandable recycler view or listview, one by one?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqXrc.png)